# Add query string to Image Source(img src) if it has a particular class or ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, if-statement

I want this in either PHP or JS. Its like, if img has particular class them a query string will be appended to its source url. Lets assume, the particular class is 'hello' & query string is '?source=fb'
So, if img has class 'hello' -

```
<img class="hello" src="http://example.com/1.jpg?source=fb">
```

The PHP should check & append it to the img src.

Any function that can do this?

Comment: Provide some more details to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('img.hello').attr('src',$('img.hello').attr('src')+"addedstring")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="hello" src="http://example.com/1.jpg?source=fb">
```

Use like this

Comment: Be careful with this method though, as if you have multiple `.hello` elements it will append the combined `src` of all of them to each other

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes this is assuming only one img with the said class

Comment: Yes, that does the job. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: glad to help mate

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `attr()` method to achieve this by providing a function to amend the current attribute value. Try this:

```
$('.hello').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src + '?source=fb';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this by Jquery. Just give another class to your image tag, assume the class 
given is "abc", it should be like :

<img class="abc hello" src="http://example.com/1.jpg">

<script>

  var image_src = $('.abc').attr('src');

  if($('.abc').hasClass('hello')){
     $('.abc').append(image_src+'?source=fb');
  }
```